# Install gcc 4.4.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc

I tried installing gcc 4.4.7 with no success, using:
`sudo apt-get install gcc 4.4.7`

I tried to run it via the source code and install a fresh one...
Nothing seems to work.

I keep getting this error:

```
Version 4.4.7 for 'gcc' was not found
```

or:

```
Couldn't find any package by glob gcc-4.4.7....
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can install gcc?  I'm new to Linux and have just installed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get to gcc 4.4.7 in Ubuntu 18.04 is to install *gcc-4.8* from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

The *gcc* package in 18.04 provides gcc 7. The latest gcc package in 18.04 is *gcc-8*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to install GCC 4.4.7 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main'
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-4.4
```

Comment: Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.2) but it is not installable